# Use fopen independently on the current directory

Tags: c, linux

Let's say I am in 2 differents directory:
On the one hand:

```
print_text_from_file.c
text_to_be_printed.txt
```

On the other hand:

```
src/
    print_text_from_file.c
    text_to_be_printed.txt
```

And the source code from the .c:

```
// can't use argv
int main(void){
    FILE *fp = fopen ("text_to_be_printed.txt", "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        // working function which takes fp and prints it as expected
        print_from_file(fp);
        fclose (fp);
    }
    else {
        printf("The file doesn't exist\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And let's say, the file only contains `Hello World !`

If I compile it 
After compiling it from being in the first directory with `gcc print_text_from_file.c`
and after executing it with `./a.out`, the output is:
`Hello world !` (exactly what I want)

However if I'm in the second case, I'll compile being on src : `gcc print_text_from_file.c`
and then execute it with being out of src: `./src/a.out`, the output is:
`The file doesn't exist`.

So basically the challenge is that I can't use argv AND I can't know from where the user will execute the file (so I don't know if using absolute paths would be correct). From anywhere, the program will have to print Hello World !.

Comment: Do you know the difference of relative and absolute path? BTW: The place where your prog was compiled is totally independent in this case here! Only the place from where it is called matters!

Comment: I'll compile with: `gcc src/print_text_from_file.c` and then execute it with: `./src/a.out`, the output is: `The file doesn't exist`.  -- it is `./src/a.out` that doesn't exits. In order to produce a `src/a.out` file you need `gcc -o src/a.out src/print_text_from_file.c` that places the executable in the `src` directory. You can always forget about that and simply `cd src` and `../a.out`. And you should really be using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -o where/you/want/exe path/to/your/source.c` to enable warnings --  and do not accept code until it compiles without a single warning.

Comment: "The file doesn't exist" is the canonical example of a bad error message. `man perror`

Comment: Which of the two files is the user allowed to move?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here:

1. gcc generates the `a.out` file at the **working directory**. It does not matter whether your build `print_text_from_file.c` or `src/print_text_from_file.c`, the `a.out` file is created at the same place, at the working directory (not at `src` directory). When you run src/a.out, I don't know what did you actually run, maybe an old artifact.
2. The file opened by the program calling fopen is relative to the working directory. If you want to open the file `src/text_to_be_printed.txt` you should give path which is relative to the working directory (i.e. `src/text_to_be_printed.txt`).

   Alternative way is to give the full path of the file. e.g. something like `/home/myuser/src/text_to_be_printed.txt`; this way, the program will find the input file, not as relative to the working directory but as absolute path.

   In order to enable the user to give you the path, you shall change the main function signature to get arguments from the user. It should be: `int main(int ac, char **av)`. The user shall run the command like this `./a.out INPUT_FILE_PATH`, where INPUT_FILE_PATH is either relative to the working directory or absolute path.
   You can access INPUT_FILE_PATH within your code as av[1]. Code will look like this:

   ```
   int main(int ac, char **av){

      const char *input_path = av[1];
      FILE *fp = fopen (input_path, "r");
      ...
   ```

Comment: Actually my bad on the first point, on the test on my machine I was doing it as it was required, I edited my post to solve this bug, my confusion writing the topic.

Following the second point, the challenge of this problem is that I can't know where the user will put the program, so I don't know his file tree, so imo, i can't use absolute paths

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect how to get path from the user

Comment: Aight, thanks but the challenge required by the exercise is that I am not allowed to use arguments from the main (neither scanf or any kind of user input) (precised in the first post), it would be a solution but I simply can't

Comment: if this is the case, I assume the user should have the input file at the working directory (the directory from where you execute your program), otherwise, how can you know the right path to the input file

Comment: I don't know. Maybe I could use the unix `cd $(find -name $(name_of_the_dir_where_a.out_is))` (where name_of... would be src here) and then cwd in order to force the program to search for the file i'm looking for from the correct view. But I have no idea how to code the cd in c and since there will probably be a lot of "src" directories, how to select the good one ?

Comment: I don't think this is the approach your lecturer meant. you can also request the user to create a symbolic link from working directory to the actual input path.
Searching for specific file within the entire file system is not recommended. you may find multiple files, you may not have access to some folders, you file system may be large, and the search will consume a lot of resources...

Answer (score 1):

You really should read something like [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) and something about [operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

And you might also look into [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)

The important notions are [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), [unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell), and [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

See also [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html), [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html), [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html), [getcwd(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html), [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html), [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)